# Change now() function's timezone

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I want to put my country's time into `reg_date` field in my db table. But `now()` puts servers time. How to change `now()` functions time to Azerbaijan (UTC +04.00)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) should return the timestamp in the current timezone as set on your system. If you can't change the timezone of the system itself, you might have to manipulate the time before you save it using PHP/Ruby/whatever, or you could opt to save the time in UTC using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.

---

Using PHP (5.3+), code to manipulate the timezone before `INSERT`ing into the database might look like:

```php
// .... some preceding stuff

$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Baku'));

$fdate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // same format as NOW()

$query = "INSERT INTO tbl (field, created_on) VALUES ('blah', '$fdate')";
mysqli_query($query);

// ... and so on
```

Comment: If you're asking about manipulating the timestamp before or after saving, I don't even know what language you're coding in. Changing the MySQL timezone requires SSH (root?) access to the server and isn't really *code*, per se.

Comment: php. i want to simply put current time of my country into db tables field. that's all

Comment: Updated my answer. (Took a wild stab at your time zone, you can find the full list [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).)

Comment: why did you take wild stab?))))

Comment: One more queston. I'm using directory structure with  header("Location: ../../../index.php"); function. If i'll put localhost/ it will work in my local webserver but not in remote one. If i'll put the exact adress of the web page then it wil not work in my local table. How can i generate websites adress with php?

Comment: That question isn't related to this one; you should ask it separately.